# Flutter - How to send push notification If the user did not logged in the app for a period of 24 hours?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-notification

I am working on a client's application using flutter, where his requirement is to send a push notification if the user did not log in to the app for a period of more than 24 hours. Is there any way this can be achieved only by flutter or should I trigger push notification from the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the user does login in app cancel all notifications previews and create a new for 24h after. For do that, use this plugin: [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and you dont need backend.